# Python binary input exception doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am slightly stuck where coding my program. My exception for not bianry input doesn't seem to work. I get this error message when I run the program, "if False in [i == '0' or i == '1' for i in bin2dec]: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable". If someone could help.

```
e1=True
print"Welcome to CJ's Program V1.00.8\n"
    while e1:
        try:
            bininput= int(input("Please enter a binary number: "))
            e1=False
        except NameError: 
            print"Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except SyntaxError: 
            print"Please try again.\n"
            time.sleep(0.5)

    if False in [i == '0' or i == '1' for i in bininput]:
        print "\nIts not Binary number. Please try again."
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print "\nIts a Binary number!\n" 

        decnum = 0 
        for i in bininput: 
            decnum = decnum * 2 + int(i)
            time.sleep(0.25)
        print decnum, "<<This is your answer.\n"
```

Comment: What the error is saying is that you cannot iterate through an integer type object, like you're trying to do on that line. Basically, you can't loop through a single number. Also, as written, you will never get to the line to input the binary number because `error1` is not defined... is that a typo?

Comment: yes sorry that is a typo. my mistake.

Comment: You should change the line giving the error to something like `if bininput not in [0,1]:` (that might not work, but you get the idea I hope).

Comment: You'll get a similar error at the line `for i in bininput:` I suspect. Also, your error message uses the name `bin2dec` but `bin2dec` is not defined in your example program...

Comment: i tried `if bininput not in [0,1]:
             print "\nIts not Binary number. Please try again." 
             time.sleep(1)`

Comment: no it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: *How* did it not work - what was the error message? I just tried a sample program using your input call and the `not in [0,1]` test, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a string you can't loop through each digit/char in an integer as people said - that's what it means.

The simplist solution to this would be to iterate through it as a string by converting the int to strings each time.

```
e1=True
print"Welcome to CJ's Program V1.00.8\n"
while e1:
    try:
        bininput= int(input("Please enter a binary number: "))
        e1=False
    except NameError: 
        print"Please try again.\n"
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except SyntaxError: 
        print"Please try again.\n"
        time.sleep(0.5)

if False in [i == '0' or i == '1' for i in str(bininput)]:
    print "\nIts not Binary number. Please try again."
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print "\nIts a Binary number!\n" 

    decnum = 0 
    for i in str(bininput): 
        decnum = decnum * 2 + int(i)
        #time.sleep(0.25)
    print decnum, "<<This is your answer.\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your suggestion works partially. Now, the problem is when I just enter numbers instead of a binary number it prints `Enter a binary. Please try again` and then loops back to the menu instead of looping back to the `Please enter a binary number: `. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The reason it doesn't go back to the `Please enter...` is because the `if` line is outside the scope of the while loop. You should indent all the rest of the lines 4 spaces if you want to go back to the entering stage after reading one number.

Comment: Yes sorry, I had to change some of your indentation to make it run so I could test it and I forgot to change it back :)